# Which table are field instance widget settings stored? Is it ok to update these everytime a node is saved?

Tags: 7, entities, feeds

I wanted to utilise the Minimum/Maximum values of Integer field instance settings. I'd like to know where these are stored in the database, and whether it's feasible to use `hook_node_save` or presave to update these min/max fields. The site will use feeds to mass import nodes, and I was wondering if it'll be ok to update these values everytime the feed import is run?

Also is there an easy way to grab these min/max values on node view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`field_info_instance()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7) to get the details, and [`field_update_instance()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_update_instance/7) to save them:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$field_name = 'field_name';
$bundle = 'content_type';

// Load
$info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);

// Get
$min = $info['settings']['min'];
$max = $info['settings']['max'];

// Set
$info['settings']['min'] = 1;
$info['settings']['max'] = 10;

// Save
field_update_instance($info);
```

I can't see any problem with updating those values during a mass import, but I can't see the benefit of doing it for every single node save. It would probably be better to run it once at the beginning/end of the import process.

You can use the same code in [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) to retrieve the values for display on the node page if you need them.